# Creating a generic linked list in c++ without stl

Tags: c++, linked-list, c++14

Can someone help creating `generic linkedlist` without `STL`. How do I declare head in main. Is it struct node<>* head ? or struct node* head ? I got a an error using both and it was something like a template declaration cannot appear at block scope

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


template<class T>
struct node
{
    T data;
    struct node<T>* next;
};

template<class T>
void Push(struct node<T>** H,T dat)
{
    struct node<T> * newnode=(struct node<T> * )malloc(sizeof(struct node<T>)) ;
    newnode->data=dat;
    newnode->next=*H;
    *H=newnode;

}


int main() {

    struct node<>* head=NULL;
    struct node<>* current;
    int a=10;
    float f=10.1;


    Push<int>(&head,a);
    Push<float>(&head,f);


    current=head;
    while(current)
    {
        cout<<current->data;
        current=current->next;
    }

    //code
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why are you not using `new` and `delete` instead of `malloc` and `free`?

Comment: Use `node<T>` insteand of `node` in `Push()`.

Comment: I am familiar with c a lot and hence I am used to it

Comment: node<T> uses stl right? I want to write linkedlist from scratch without using  STL much

Comment: Using `malloc` in a simple case like this works, but it only allocate memory. The `new` operator does more (like calling constructors).

Comment: Also, templates are a *compiler* thing. The standard library uses it extensively, but it's not something library-specific. I think you need to find [a good beginners book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) and start over with that.

Comment: Finally, `node` is a *template*, it's sort of a blueprint for a class but not a finished class. `node<T>` is a concrete class that can be instantiated into objects.

Comment: You can't have nodes with different types in the same list.

Comment: In `main`, you can't use `node<>` because there is no such thing as `node<>`. You could use `node<int>` or `node<float>` depending on whether you want a list of ints or a list of floats.

Comment: I am using template to have a mix of int and float in my linked list. So how do I go about that in main?

Comment: @NiranjanKotha That is not what templates do.

Comment: The first thing you need to do for learning C++ is forget most of C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, this is a weird mix of C and C++ style programming. But let's ignore that and focus on your real question. Your primary issue is that you're not specifying a type parameter when referencing `node` (should be `node<T>` when you use it). So changing that first bit to:

```
template<class T>
struct node
{
    T data;
    struct node<T>* next; 
};

template<class T>
void Push(struct node<T>** H,T dat) // <-- now we use node<T> everywhere
{
    struct node<T> * newnode=(struct node<T> * )malloc(sizeof(struct node<T>)) ;
    newnode->data=dat;
    newnode->next=*H;
    *H=newnode;

}
```

Should get you where you need to go. There, you're properly referring to it as `node<T>` everywhere in `Push`. Same will apply to `main()`. Now `malloc` will work, as a `node<T>` does have a definite size.

That said, you'll find it a bit cleaner to use `node<T> *example = new node<T>` and `delete example` instead.

There are a number of other improvements that could be made to move this more into the C++ realm but I'm just focusing on your direct question here; move on to the rest later.

Comment: can you modify the main function too since I am getting some errors like what is the template argument I need to give declaring head. Is it struct node<>* head ? Thanks !

Comment: @NiranjanKotha The modifications that need to be made to `main()` and everywhere else are exactly the same as the ones shown here. You might want to check out http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_templates.htm.